# latex3: \tl_case not properly detecting value of a token

Tags: expl3, latex3

I am creating a package with different internal functions that can be setup with the tokens provided during the initialization of the package. Inside the package, everything is written using the latex3 syntaxis.

I stumbled across a problem when evaluating a token using a "switch-case"-like command, specifically using the \tl_case:NnTF. When calling my command \checkStyle I cannot manage to make it enter in the right case, the output in the document should be A, B, or C.

I suspect it is something very simple, but my low knowledge in latex3 does not allow me to find the source. I provide a minimal working example here below.

I hope you can help. Thanks in advance.

**typeset.sty**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{typeset}[2021/12/16 Typesetting Package]

% ------------------------  Load required packages
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

% ----------Trial
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Definition of the package options
\keys_define:nn { typeset }
{ 
% Create token list with opts
opt .tl_set:N = \l_typeset_opt_tl ,
deg .tl_set:N = \l_typeset_deg_tl ,
opt .initial:n = altern ,
deg .initial:n = other ,
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Process package options
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProcessKeysOptions{ typeset }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Create test case
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{ \test }
{
Content:~ \l_typeset_opt_tl ,  ~is~type~ \checkStyle{ \l_typeset_opt_tl }
\\
Content:~ \l_typeset_deg_tl , ~is~type~ \checkStyle{ \l_typeset_deg_tl } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff 
 
 
% Token list switch-case 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_mytoken_tl
\tl_const:Nn \c__altern_tl { altern }
\tl_const:Nn \c__nomin_tl { nomin }
\tl_const:Nn \c__other_tl { other }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \checkStyle #1 
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytoken_tl { #1 }
    \tl_case:NnTF \l_mytoken_tl 
{
    \c__altern_tl {A}
    \c__nomin_tl {B}
    \c__other_tl {C}
}
  {}
  {None} 
  \\
  Input~to ~checkstyle~was: {#1}  
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\endinput
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[opt=nomin]{typeset}

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you put `\ExplSyntaxOn/\ExplSyntaxOff` around every block of code?

Comment: When I simplified my code, I had to eliminate several other sections of the package. This package includes pieces of `latex3` and `latex2e`. Therefore, every time I need to use the synthaxis of latex3 I use `\ExplSyntaxOn/\ExplSyntaxOff`. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: I'd group everything that needs to be inside of `expl3`-syntax in one block so that I reduce the overhead of calling multiple `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Comment: @Skillmon: thanks for the advice :) . I changed the code, the results remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is an expansion problem. When you call `\checkStyle{\l_typeset_opt_tl}` this will create a token list like the following:

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytoken_tl { \l_typeset_opt_tl }
```

and this will be compared to something containing `altern` or something like that, which is obviously not the same. Instead you should expand your token list before forwarding it. But all in all I'd argue that for your use case you shouldn't use `\tl_case:Nn` but `\str_case:nn` instead.

Additionally your package is using a rather wild mix of naming style. Inside `expl3`-syntax *all* your variables, constants and macros should follow the naming convention of `expl3`, and that is not to use `\l_mytoken_tl` but instead `\l_typeset_mytoken_tl` or something like that (always include the module name).

I'd use the following code for your package:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage{typeset}{2021/12/16}{0.0}{Typesetting Package}

% ------------------------  Load required packages
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

% ----------Trial

% Definition of the package options
\keys_define:nn { typeset }
  {
    % Create string with opts
    opt .str_set:N = \l__typeset_opt_str ,
    deg .str_set:N = \l__typeset_deg_str ,
    opt .initial:n = altern ,
    deg .initial:n = other ,
  }

% Process package options
\ProcessKeysOptions{ typeset }

% Create test case
\NewDocumentCommand \test {}
  {
    Content:~ \str_use:N \l__typeset_opt_str ,  ~is~type~
      \typeset_check_style:V \l__typeset_opt_str
    \\
    Content:~ \str_use:N \l__typeset_deg_str , ~is~type~
      \typeset_check_style:V \l__typeset_deg_str 
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \typeset_check_style:n #1
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        { altern } {A}
        { nomin  } {B}
        { other  } {C}
      }
      {None}
    \\
    Input~to ~checkstyle~was: #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \typeset_check_style:n { V }

\endinput
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to test the *contents* of the variables, not the variables.

### `typeset.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{typeset}[2021/12/16 Typesetting Package]

% ------------------------  Load required packages
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

% ----------Trial
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Definition of the package options
\keys_define:nn { typeset }
 {
  % Create token list with opts
  opt .tl_set:N = \l_typeset_opt_tl ,
  deg .tl_set:N = \l_typeset_deg_tl ,
  opt .initial:n = altern ,
  deg .initial:n = other ,
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Process package options
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProcessKeysOptions{ typeset }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Create test case
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{ \test }
  {
    Content:~ \l_typeset_opt_tl ,  ~is~type~ \typeset_checkstyle:V \l_typeset_opt_tl
    \\
    Content:~ \l_typeset_deg_tl , ~is~type~ \typeset_checkstyle:V \l_typeset_deg_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff 
 
 
% Token list switch-case 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_mytoken_tl
\tl_const:Nn \c__altern_tl { altern }
\tl_const:Nn \c__nomin_tl { nomin }
\tl_const:Nn \c__other_tl { other }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \typeset_checkstyle:n #1 
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytoken_tl { #1 }
    \tl_case:NnF \l_mytoken_tl 
      {
        \c__altern_tl {A}
        \c__nomin_tl {B}
        \c__other_tl {C}
      }
      {None} 
  \\
  Input~to ~checkstyle~was: {#1}  
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \typeset_checkstyle:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\endinput
```

### `test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[opt=nomin]{typeset}

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this was not obvious to me. I am trying to learn `latex3`, but due to the lack of examples in the documentation, this is slow.